# Генерируется исключение при вызове NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Debug(string someoutput)

Tags: linux, .net, nlog, core

Есть приложение, которое написано на C# .NET Core (собран под Linux). В нем используется вызов `NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Debug(string someoutput)`. Проблема в том, что периодически во время этого вызова генерируется исключение:

```
System.ArgumentException: The ConsoleColor enum value was not defined on that enum. Please use a defined color from the enum.
   at System.ConsolePal.RefreshColors(ConsoleColor& toChange, ConsoleColor value)
   at NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleSystemPrinter.ChangeForegroundColor(TextWriter consoleWriter, Nullable`1 foregroundColor)
   at NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleTarget.ColorizeEscapeSequences(IColoredConsolePrinter consolePrinter, TextWriter consoleWriter, String message, Nullable`1 defaultForegroundColor, Nullable`1 defaultBackgroundColor, Nullable`1 rowForegroundColor, Nullable`1 rowBackgroundColor)
   at NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleTarget.WriteToOutputWithPrinter(TextWriter consoleStream, String colorMessage, Nullable`1 newForegroundColor, Nullable`1 newBackgroundColor, Boolean wordHighlighting)
   at NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleTarget.WriteToOutputWithColor(LogEventInfo logEvent, String message)
   at NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleTarget.WriteToOutput(LogEventInfo logEvent, String message)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncThreadSafe(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvent(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.LoggerImpl.WriteToTargetWithFilterChain(Target target, FilterResult result, LogEventInfo logEvent, AsyncContinuation onException)
   at NLog.LoggerImpl.Write(Type loggerType, TargetWithFilterChain targetsForLevel, LogEventInfo logEvent, LogFactory factory)
```

Я так понимаю, NLog не может инициализировать перечисление с нужным цветом консоли. Из-за чего такое может происходить?

Answer (score 0):

Данная ошибка оказалось дефектом NLog, проблема устранилась после обновления пакета